# Express Love in different way/context

Tags: meaning

I have a very confused question that has always haunted in my mind, I've intended several time to check it out when it poped out from someone's mouth in the television.

***The question is that why people claim "I loved her/him" rather than "I love her/him" given that the one they refer to is already dead.*** Is't it the LOVE supposed to be an emotion or affection for someone to another. ***And as I have been told that the past tense should be something which is not  meant to be appeared at the present.*** This is to say, the speaker won't love the dead one anymore which is seemingly inappropriate in the context of Chinese.

In Chinese, for example, if a couple love each other, and then one of them died (no particular things occur like divorce or fighting), we do not tend to say I loved her/him. This, in Chinese context, is "I used love her/him, and I do not love anymore." ***Put it simply, no matter how far the one has gone, we still love her/him. There is no past tense. Love always maintains, in our memory.***

Comment: Can you clarify. Both "I love him" and "I loved him" might be used of someone who has died. Which one do you find odd?

Comment: Yes, the her/him has died. Since in our culture, when someone's partner, lover, who is important to himself has died, the guy would say like in the funeral "I love him/her" which in Chinese is "我爱她/他" 而不是 " 我爱过他/她”. In Chinese there is no past tense being used", which is different to English expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no grammatical rule that speakers should use the past tense or present tense when speaking of their love for another person who has died.  This is entirely a cultural and personal matter.

A person could say

> I loved him when he was alive and continue to love him now that he is gone. He will always have a place in my heart.